# Python : Word by word Text Processing between two files

Tags: python, string, nlp, text-processing

I'm new to NLP. I have two text files. First file has `dialogues` formatted properly  like below .

```
    RECEPTIONIST Can I help you?
    LINCOLN Yes. Um, is this the State bank?
    RECEPTIONIST If you have to ask, maybe you shouldn't be here.
    SARAH I think this is the place.
    RECEPTIONIST Fill in the query.
    LINCOLN Thank-you. We'll be right back.
    RECEPTIONIST Oh, take your time. I'll just finish my crossword puzzle.
    oh, wait.
```

The Second text file has 7 columns . In 5th column I have the words sequence from the dialogues of like below .

```
    Column 5
    Can
    I
    help
    you
    ?
    yes
    .
    Um
    ,
```

The Full stop and commas are considered as words here and if it has 3 or more full stop's together like `"..."`  then it should be considered as a single word. Also if the words `"Thank-you"` (because they don't have space in between them) should be considered as a single word.

Now I want to write a script in python to compare each word from the `dialogues` and then make a new column (Column 8) which should show **" who speaks the word "** . Like below

```
    Column 5           Column 8
    Can                RECEPTIONIST
    I                  RECEPTIONIST
    help               RECEPTIONIST
    you                RECEPTIONIST
    ?                  RECEPTIONIST  
    yes                LINCOLN
    .                  LINCOLN
    Um                 LINCOLN
    ,                  LINCOLN
```

[image]

As I'm completely new to python environment. I dont know where to start .Please provide your suggestion and any tips to coding!

The first file has the dialogues and the second file has information about the dialogues

Comment: How are these columns represented in the 2 text files you mentioned? Could you paste a snippet of such a text file? Are the columns separated with a tab, space, comma (csv file?).

Comment: @Djanssend : I updated with Snippet . Please go through it .Both are text files

Comment: Do you want to compare each line of `dialogues` with content of second text file?

Comment: Yes I want to compare . Else the identity of the character dialogues will be missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest the following steps to perform:

**Process text file 1**

here you want to split the string like `LEONARD Agreed, what's your point`into
a set of tokens. A naive approach is to use `split(" ")` which will split the text based on spaces, however you also need to take in consideration punctuations.

I suggest to use NLTK, a python library for natural language processing. A basic example will show how this might help you:

```
import nltk
sentence = """Hi this is a test."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
# output: tokens
['Hi', 'this', "is", 'a', 'test', '.']
```

Once you have tokenised each sentence **correctly**, you will know how many lines it will have in the second text file.

**Process text file 2**

Now you will iterate over each line in the second text file, you check if the word matches the supposed token which you found in the first step. If this is the case you add the first token (the name of the person who said it) to the end of the line (column 8).

You can get the word from the string `TheBigBangTheory.Season01.Episode01.en 1 59.160 0.070 you 0.990 lex`by simply doing `sentence.split(" ")[4]`, which returns `you`in this case.

I believe it will still need some tweaking, but I'll leave that to you. This might outline the general idea.

Goodluck, Bazinga!